# Dependency Injection how to re-add all services to builder.Services after config change

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, .net-maui

This question is specific to NET Maui in my case.

My Settings file:

```
{
  "MyConfig": {
      "FactoryConfig1": {
           "SomeType1": "SomeConfig1"
       },
        "FactoryConfig2": {
            "SomeType2": "SomeConfig2"
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I'm creating my services like this:

```cs
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService2, Service2>();   
builder.Services.AddTransient<Service3>();

// and config file-- how to modify this to use IOptions to use with IOptions Monitor?
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiBlazorTestApp.appsettings.json");

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonStream(stream)
    .Build();
builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);

return builder.Build();
```

then in another class I get the config:

```cs
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Service1(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {      
        var myConfig = _configuration.GetRequiredSection("MyConfig").Get<MyConfig>();        
    }
 }
```

In each of the services, I'm injecting an IConfiguration with the configuration parameters used in each service from an `appsettings.json` file.

*The code above works the way it is* but what if sometime after starting the app, and after the services have been already created with the existing settings, the user changes some settings in appsettings.json from a UI dashboard page, how can I reload all those services with the new config settings for each...

I have to clear the services, and re-add them, is this possible, in a class outside program.cs?
It would work if I restart the application, but can it be done without, just a refresh of the DI?

Comment: Explicitly injecting IConfiguration is a code smell IMO (Because of the very issues you are experiencing). I suggest you read up on the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) and IOptionsMonitor for the scenario described in the above post

Comment: @Nkosi I can't get IOptions to work in this example in Net Maui, how do I set that up please? I added more code to show what I have right now working

Answer (score 2):

As @Nkosi mentioned in the comments you should always use option pattern and not directly access the `IConfiguration` object.

In your case just use a class to store the desired values from configuration:

```cs
public class MyConfig 
{
   // The class to bind IConfiguration to
   public string YourSetting { get; set; }
}
```

add options to the service collection and configure them. Also note the `reloadOnChange` parameter used during setup which indicates whether the configuration is reloaded if the file changes.

```cs
//...

builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("MauiBlazorTestApp.appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

// Add and configure your options
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("MyConfig"));

//...
```

and finally inject the options into the target services and access the settings as needed.

```cs
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<MyConfig> _options;

    public Service1(IOptionsMonitor<MyConfig> options) 
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        // Read the current value provided via IConfiguration
        MyConfig appSettings = _options.CurrentValue;
        var value = appSettings.YourSetting;

        //...use setting as needed
    }
}
```

When ever the current setting is requested, it will pull the latest version from settings, even if the service is a singeton.

For more information you can find this pattern very well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) and especially for the `IOptionsMonitor` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1.currentvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-options-ioptionsmonitor-1-currentvalue)

Comment: and Nkosi thanks for the answer, but specifically in .NET Maui I can't get IOptions to work, only IConfiguration, not sure how to set that up. I updated my question with more details

Comment: Also, if IOptions are updated, are the singleton services using the config, re-initiated with the new settings? Those settings are used in the constructor of Service1 and Sertice2 to configure the services.

Comment: @Nkosi /Martin, I am trying this solution right now and again thank you so much for it, one more question, what is "Configuration" in this line: builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(Configuration);  Does this point to the "appsettings.json"? Do I have tto remove the code that currently points to the appsettings.json from my question? I looked at the links but its not clear what and how to build that "Configuration"

Comment: You probably want `.Configure<MyConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"))`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I tried that way, and itdoesn't work in Maui, options are null when injected with IOptionsMonitor, not sure what is going wrong

Comment: @Nkosi the problem is here: builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(builder.Configuration); error says: Cannot convert from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to System.Action<MyConfig> in ConfigurationManager MauiAppBuilder.Configuration

Comment: @RazvanEmil I suggest debugging start up code and ensure the appsettings are actually being read. If options is null it means it is not finding the matching configuration

Comment: @Nkosi the file is read fine when I used IConfiguration, but wil debug again, see if I see anything relevant to why its not working.

Comment: @RazvanEmil if you use the stream like in your original example, that is a onetime read and wont see updates.

Comment: @Nkosi I understand thanks for that. This: builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("MyConfig")); doesnt'; work because in Maui it's asking for an Action<MyConfig> configureOptions as param for builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>()

Comment: Then you are missing an extension. Check to make sure you have all the necessary packages installed/referenced.

Comment: @Nkosi nothing comes into the import intellisense, so far I have:

using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using MyApp.Common.MyConfig;

Comment: Note the available overloads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: Missing `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace

Comment: @Nkosi i imported it, but still nothing. Control+. also doesn't suggest any other imports. I also added appsettings.json structure if helps

Comment: @RazvanEmil you should install this package **Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions** to resolve this issue, "Cannot convert from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to System.Action<MyConfig> in ConfigurationManager MauiAppBuilder.Configuration"